# Page missing/dropped from Google

Tags: google, google-index

This is bizarre: One of my pages seems to have completely dropped from Google. It used to be ranking really well, then suddenly it's gone. The URL is not in Google at all.

It doesn't have a `noindex` tag, or a *robots.txt* to not index it either. It has simply vanished from Google. There is nothing spammy about it whatsoever, and the site has no penalties. Any idea what has caused this, and how to recover?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I would look over your Google Webmaster Tools stats to see if there is any relevant information.  You should be able to see a timeline of the number of pages listed in your sitemap vs. the number of pages indexed in Google.

The way Google operates these days, they could have removed your page for duplicate content, weak content, copyright concerns, outside spam links, non family friendly content, deceptive ad placement, or for no observable reason at all.

There is also the "site made for search engines" penalty that drives me crazy as there are suggestions from Google regarding how to make you site more "search engine friendly".  If the bots don't like your page, there isn't much you can do after the fact.

My advice, if you cannot figure out the issue would be to move on. Delete the page and create it again in a different form.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me quite a few times with different sites, with no rhyme or reason as to why it may have happened.

Each time I have submitted the URL back to Google (either [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) or via [fetch as Google in Web Master Tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en)), and the next day the page was indexed again.

The only thing I could think of that may have caused it is possibly downtime on the page.

[Here is a recent post on Moz on the same subject](http://moz.com/blog/panic-stations-how-to-handle-an-important-page-disappearing-from-google-case-study). Although again, he didn't find out why it happened and just resubmitted to Google.